# Rotating an object on X Y axis, cocos3D

Tags: rotation, gesture, pan, cocos3d

I'm using Cocos3D on iOs. I need to rotate an object using pan gesture.

```
switch (gesture.state)
{
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        saveState = Dobj.rotation;
    break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        CC3Vector rotateVector = CC3VectorMake(gesture.translation.y, gesture.translation.x, 0.0f);
        Dobj.rotation = CC3VectorAdd(saveState, rotateVector);
    break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

This way I can get my object(`Dobj`) to rotate on itself. But it seems that the axis is also rotating and that is causing some really weird rotation.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how I solved my problem.

```
switch (gesture.state)
{
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        saveState = CC3VectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
         CC3Vector rotateVector = CC3VectorMake(gesture.translation.y, gesture.translation.x, 0.0f);
        [Dobj rotateBy:CC3VectorDifference(rotateVector, saveState)];
        saveState = rotateVector;
    break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Using the method `rotateBy:` seems to rotate the object only without changing its axis